# Django filter OR - q objects performance vs I performance

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter, django-q

What will have better performance? Which is faster? Which implies lower db load?

```
Item.objects.filter(Q(creator=owner) | Q(moderated=False))
```

or

```
result = Item.objects.filter(item.creator = owner) | Item.objects.filter(item.moderated = False)
```

Comment: Most likely the first one, as it will be one query instead of two. [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) is a good tool to see which is faster for certain.

Comment: The first one - It is a single query with joins, versus  the second one which is 2 queries which are chained. Also, the second case would not work if you slice.

Comment: Have you compared the SQL they generate? Django should handle this as a single query and I would expect them to be identical.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These should generate identical SQL. I don't have your model definition but using the `auth.User` model you can see it is the same:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> q1 = User.objects.filter(Q(is_staff=True) | Q(is_superuser=True))
>>> print(q1.query)
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE ("auth_user"."is_staff" = True OR "auth_user"."is_superuser" = True)
>>> q2 = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True) | User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
>>> print(q2.query)
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE ("auth_user"."is_staff" = True OR "auth_user"."is_superuser" = True)
>>> str(q1.query) == str(q2.query)
True
```